# Setting table width at 100% does not fill area

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having an issue with my table, I have set the width to **100%** in the CSS however it still does not seem to work. Setting the `<td>` widths seem to be working however.

Heres the **HTML:**

```
<table id="events-table">
   <tr class="primary">
      <td>Event</td>
      <td>Acts</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>Date</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample Acts</td>
      <td>Sample Location</td>
      <td>Friday 16/06/12 22:00</td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample Acts</td>
      <td>Sample Location</td>
      <td>Friday 16/06/12 22:00</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Here is the **CSS:**

```
table#events-table { width:100%; }
table#events-table td { padding:6px; }
table#events-table td:nth-child(1) { width:30%; }
table#events-table td:nth-child(2) { width:25%; }
table#events-table td:nth-child(3) { width:25%; }
table#events-table td:nth-child(4) { width:20%; }
table#events-table tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background:#222; }
table#events-table tr:nth-of-type(even) { background:#111; }
#events-table .primary { font-weight:bold; background:#000 !important; }
```

I believe it may be something in my stylesheet that is conflicting with it but I can't get my finger on what it is.

Comment: On a side note, look at using `<thead>` to style your table header and `<tbody>` to style the "normal" rows. You shouldn't need a `.primary` class to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `float:left` from `class` **col** seems to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, problem in `class` **col** ( **style.css - line 4** )

```
.col {
   display: inline;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
```